# Spark Scala convert RDD with Case Class to simple RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, case-class

This is fine:

```scala
case class trans(atm : String, num: Int)
    
val array = Array((20254552,"ATM",-5100), (20174649,"ATM",5120))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(array)
val rdd1 = rdd.map(x => (x._1, trans(x._2, x._3)))
```

How to convert back to a simple RDD like rdd again?

E.g. `rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String, Int)]`

I can do this, for sure:

```
val rdd2 = rdd1.mapValues(v => (v.atm, v.num)).map(x => (x._1, x._2._1, x._2._2))
```

but what if there is a big record for the class? E.g. dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly how generic you want to go, but in your example of an `RDD[(Int, trans)]` you can make use of the `unapply` method of the `trans` companion object in order to flatten your case class to a tuple.

So, if you have your setup:

```scala
case class trans(atm : String, num: Int)

val array = Array((20254552,"ATM",-5100), (20174649,"ATM",5120))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(array)
val rdd1 = rdd.map(x => (x._1, trans(x._2, x._3)))
```

You can do the following:

```scala
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

val output = rdd1.map{
  case (myInt, myTrans) => {
    myInt +: trans.unapply(myTrans).get
  }
}
output
res15: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String, Int)]
```

We're importing `shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._` in order to be able to make a tuple from our Int + flattened tuple (the `myInt +: trans.unapply(myTrans).get` operation).

Answer (score 1):

Case class method "productIterator" can help convert to array:

```
case class trans(atm : String, num: Int)
val value = trans("ATM", 5120)
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(value))
rdd
  .map(_.productIterator.toArray)
```

Comment: I will try but I see no cases class usage your side.

Comment: Yours case class "trans" is used in my example in first line.

Comment: yes, but it is not a case class

Comment: answer was updated, case class added

Comment: OK, I will try tonight, not so generic though. Let me look.

Comment: get an array of any, not quite the same thing

Comment: rdd4: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Any])]  is something that we get and cannot work with.

Comment: Not sure it is actually possible.